# Module dependency to generated jar

Tags: maven-2

I have one project (called EJB server) that contains X-Doclet annotated EJB service and a client project (module) that depends on client jar generated from server project.

What is best practice in maven for setting such dependencies when one project (module) depends on JAR which is generated from other module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible scenarios:

If you develop these two modules in parallel and are part of the same project then create a parent POM and declare the two modules. Depending module (client) should declare as a dependency the declaring one (server).

If both modules are developed separately then release the server, declare that client depends on server and let the maven retrieve the server from your private repository.

Comment: Well, that's ok, like a standard dependency. However, in this scenario, JAR is generated from server module, and client module should only depend on this JAR not whole server module

Comment: Then the second scenario will cover your needs.